# installing pygobject on mac for Python 2.6

Tags: python, macos, pygobject

Does anyone know how to install PyGObject on Mac OSX for Python 2.6. The current distribution available on darwinports is using Python2.4. I want a package using Python2.6

Alternatively, has anyone tried installing it from sources on a Mac?

Answer (score 9):

If you have [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) you can simply do

```
port install py26-gobject
```

With [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) it would be:

```
brew install pygobject
```

Comment: `brew install pygobject` does no longer work. The formula does no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [pygobject](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pygobject3.rb) with Python 3 and GTK 3:

```
brew install pygobject3
```

Answer (score -1):

ah found it : http://py26-gobject.darwinports.com/

nevermind!